# create a file from user input

Tags: python, file

Anyone can help me on this task. I'm new to Python. I'm trying to accomplished this:
The filename should be hardcode name called: Server_Information.txt and and the second column should be inserted by the user input but the date stamp.
Built By : john doe
Build Date: %d%m%y
Build Reason: Playground
Requestor: john doe

Maybe I can use this test script but the first column does not show in the final test file.

Thank you for anyone it helps

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file.  Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("Built By : ")
line2 = raw_input("Build Date: %d%m%y ")
line3 = raw_input("Build Reason: ")
line4 = raw_input("Requestor: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line4)

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write this, because now you do not record the invitation as a file.

```
target.write('%s: %s\n' % ('Built By', line1))
target.write('%s: %s\n' % ('Build Date', line2))
target.write('%s: %s\n' % ('Build Reason', line3))
target.write('%s: %s\n' % ('Requestor', line4))
```

Comment: Same here I replacing my target.write with yours and is not working is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing and reopening the file after the truncate()

```
 target.close()
 target = open(filename, 'w')
 # ask for user input here
 # and close file
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `raw_input` returns only the input entered by user, not include the messages you used to prompt, so you need to add those messages to `line1` manually, like this:

```
line1 = "Built By : " + raw_input("Built By : ")
```

And for `line2` I think you want to generate it automatically instead of asking user to enter, you can do it like this:

```
line2 = "Build Date: " + time.strftime("%d%m%Y", time.localtime())
```

Comment: WKplus, Thank you for you input. I cannot get it to work. I'm getting error name not defined. I run in a debugger mode. python -m pdb script.py but as son I put the name of the file it dies.

Comment: @pirulo You need to add `import time` before you use `time.strftime` .